# Same id with diffent classname in html and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ios, ipad, uiwebview

I have a situation where

```
<label id="studentName" class="firstClass> </label>
<label id="studentName" class="secondClass> </label>
<label id="registerNumber" class="firstClass> </label>
<label id="registerNumber" class="secondClass> </label>
```

Now, I have to identify each tag uniquely and replace the innerHTML with some value, using class and id.

How Can I achieve this from javascript/ios side ?

Comment: ID must be unique in the document.

Comment: Isn't the id property for identifying?

Answer (score 2):

You want to switch the Id and classes around. You CANT have 2 of the same ID's But you can have multible Classes with the same name.

```
<label id="firststudentName" class="studentName> </label>
<label id="secondstudentName" class="studentName> </label>
<label id="firstregisterNumber" class="registerNumber> </label>
<label id="secondregisterNumber" class="registerNumber> </label>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
elements = document.getElementsByClassName(names);
```

and loop on the results, there is also hasClass function.

But normally an ID should be unique.

Answer (score 0):

try this with jquery:

```
function checkUnique(className){
    var count = 0;
    var ids = '';
    $('.' + className).each(function(i){
        if(ids.indexOf($(this).attr('id')) != -1){
            $(this).attr('id',$(this).attr('id') + i);
        }
        ids += $(this).attr('id');
    })
}
```

Comment: hicurin, is it possible for you to give the same method in the javascript and not in jquery.? I use only javascript from iPad applications' webview.

Answer (score -1):

This is invalid HTML, see here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_id.asp

If you're iterating through e.g. a number of students, make sure to use the cycle for the id so you have

`id="studentName1"`
`id="studentName2"`